# Fetching a dynamic stash list

Tags: categories, stash, ee3, nested-list

I am trying to build out a list of categories that I need to include in the nav as well as other sections of a site. I had it done with embeds and `{exp:category}` loops, but I would rather be able to pull what I need using stash if possible.

I want to create two separate lists. One will be the locations (or parent categories. The second will be the category children. I need to be able to relate the category children. This is why I have the kid's list being created using the  parent category name.

I am getting what I need by doing the following:

```
{!-- LOCATIONS --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="locations" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:categories
        category_group='2'
        style='linear'
        parent_only='yes'
    }
        {stash:location}{category_name}{/stash:location}
        {stash:url}{category_url_title}{/stash:url}
    {/exp:channel:categories}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- LOCATIONS KIDS --}
{exp:stash:parse}
    {exp:channel:categories
        category_group='2'
        style='linear'
    }
        {if parent_id == '0'}
            {if count > '1'}
                {/exp:stash:set_list}
            {/if}
            {exp:stash:set_list name="{category_name}_kids" parse_tags="yes"}
        {if:else}
            {if count == total_results}
                    {stash:kid}{category_name}{/stash:kid}
                    {stash:kid_url}{category_url_title}{/stash:kid_url}
                {/exp:stash:set_list}
            {if:else}
                {stash:kid}{category_name}{/stash:kid}
                {stash:kid_url}{category_url_title}{/stash:kid_url}
            {/if}
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:categories}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

I can pull the locations manually, and I can pull the kids manually. What I NEED to be able to do is pull them dynamically by relationship. I tried this, but it doesn't render the kids.

```
{exp:stash:get_list name='locations'}
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="{site_url}find-your-home/{url}">{location} <b class="caret-right"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {exp:stash:get_list name='{location}_kids'}
                <li>
                    <a href="{site_url}find-your-home/{url}/{kid_url}">{kid}</a>
                </li>
            {/exp:stash:get_list}
        </ul>
    </li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Is there something I am missing or can I not build out a dynamic list call?

Comment: On a side note: I could be wrong but, you might not need that exp:stash:parse tag if you add [parse_conditionals](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset%7D#parse_conditionals---yes--no-) to the set_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to take in account the fact that you're [nesting](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset_list%7D#nesting).

```
{exp:stash:get_list name='locations'}
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="{site_url}find-your-home/{url}">{location} <b class="caret-right"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {exp:stash:get_list:nested name='{location}_kids'}
                <li>
                    <a href="{site_url}find-your-home/{url}/{kid_url}">{kid}</a>
                </li>
            {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
        </ul>
    </li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same situation, however some of the main menu items (parent categories) dont have children (sub categories)

How can I make the caret display conditionally only if there are sub menu items?

Thanks so much, this has helped me a lot already!

Comment: This is what my issue was (in the end) as well. If you are using stash, just create a field as a flag and use logic to check for existence or not. If you aren't using stash, then check for them on THOSE particular nav segments and use them if needed.